# Download 1 week data from instaloader

Tags: instagram, instaloader

When we download data from instagram, it scans the entire posts of the account even when you provide a time window(it will skip the dates older but will still scan the whole history) through the following command:

```
instaloader --login=username
--password=password
--post-metadata-txt="{likes} likes, {comments} comments." 
--post-filter="date_utc >= datetime(2019, 12, 31) and not is_video"
```

This is very inefficient. I am wondering is there any more efficient way to download data?

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly supported by Instaloader's command line interface, meaning that you have to write a little Python script to achieve that. There is an example in the Instaloader documentation for [downloading posts in a specific period](https://instaloader.github.io/codesnippets.html#download-posts-in-a-specific-period). It differs from what you want to achieve in only very few points:

- Use a custom *post_metadata_txt_pattern*. To do so, instantiate Instaloader with

  ```py
  L = instaloader.Instaloader(post_metadata_txt_pattern="{likes} likes, {comments} comments.")
  ```
- Log in:

  ```py
  L.load_session_from_file('username')
  ```
- Load until the latest post (Not having a specific *SINCE* date). This allows for a even simpler loop. Also filter by *not is_video*:

  ```py
  for post in takewhile(lambda p: p.date_utc > datetime(2019, 12, 31), posts):
      if not post.is_video:
          L.download_post(post, 'target_directory')
  ```

The key is the *takewhile* function, which ends the download loop when a post is encountered that does not match the given condition. Considering that posts come newest-first, the download loop terminates as soon as all new-enough posts have been downloaded.

Putting it all together, we get:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import takewhile

import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader(post_metadata_txt_pattern="{likes} likes, {comments} comments.")

L.load_session_from_file('username')

posts = L.get_hashtag_posts('hashtag')
# or
# posts = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, 'profile').get_posts()

for post in takewhile(lambda p: p.date_utc > datetime(2019, 12, 31), posts):
    if not post.is_video:
        L.download_post(post, 'target_directory')
```

Write that in a file, e.g. *downloader.py* and execute it with *python downloader.py*. The call to *load_session_from_file* assumes that there's already a saved Instaloader session, to get one, simply call *instaloader -l username* before executing the code snippet.